# How to return a result to ui from multiple Rest API calls in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have 4 API request for money transfer

1. Authorize
2. GetBeneficiary
3. AddBenificiary
4. RequestTransfer

Now I need to get the result of request transfer and return to the UI and say 'Transfer is successful', and also if any of those API fail in between I need to send to the UI.

I have return something like this:

```
authorize(){
getBeificiary();
}
getBeificiary(){
if(no benificiary){
addBeificiary();
}else{
requestTransfer();
}

addBenificiary(){
requestTransfer();
}

requestTransfer(){
return 'message';
}
```

Comment: First call all your api's in the initState() and when the result of the api is successful, set the value to a variable. Do this for all apis, when all the api has finished successfully in setting to a variable, turn of any loaders. Then just reload your ui with the data set in the variables.

Comment: you can use `async` & `await`, these will do what you are looking for, you should `wait` till the requests are done, then update your UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
var response=Future.wait([<list of apis>]);
// use response as response[0], response[1] as respective to the apis given in the line.
```